# Replacing SystemColors in Wpf throws ArgumentException

Tags: wpf

Rather than creating explicit new styles for every control I thought I would come a long way just replacing the colors. I tried adding the below to my App.xaml. In this case it should correspond to the original Windows 7 Aero colors, so no change should be visible.

The strange part is that I get the following exception, why does it seem to use the color value as key? What am I missing?

```
System.ArgumentException: {"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '#FF000000'  Key being added: '#FF000000'"}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Frankenbuild.Wpf.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!-- aero original colors -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColor}" Color="#FFB4B4B4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColor}" Color="#FF99B4D1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor}" Color="#FFABABAB"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColor}" Color="#FFA0A0A0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkColor}" Color="#FF696969"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColor}" Color="#FFE3E3E3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColor}" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.DesktopColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionColor}" Color="#FFB9D1EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaptionColor}" Color="#FFD7E4F2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextColor}" Color="#FF6D6D6D"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" Color="#FF3399FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackColor}" Color="#FF0066CC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderColor}" Color="#FFF4F7FC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionColor}" Color="#FFBFCDDB"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionTextColor}" Color="#FF434E54"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InfoColor}" Color="#FFFFFFE1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InfoTextColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuColor}" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarColor}" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightColor}" Color="#FF3399FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarColor}" Color="#FFC8C8C8"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowColor}" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameColor}" Color="#FF646464"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextColor}" Color="#FF000000"/>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `ResourceKey`s instead... so instead of this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColor}" Color="#FFB4B4B4"/>
```

... try this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}" Color="#FFB4B4B4"/>
```

For more information, take a look at the [SystemColors Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.